# Path to bundle of iOS framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, bundle

I am working on a framework for iOS, which comes with some datafiles. To load them into a `Dictionary` I do something like this:

```
public func loadPListFromBundle(filename: String, type: String) -> [String : AnyObject]? {
    guard
       let bundle = Bundle(for: "com.myframework")
       let path = bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: type),
       let plistDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String : AnyObject]
    else { 
       print("plist not found")
       return nil 
    }

    return plistDict
}
```

If I use this in a playground with the framework, it works as intended.

But if I use the framework embedded in an app, it doesn't work anymore, the "path" now points to the bundle of the app, not of the framework.

How do I make sure that the bundle of the framework is accessed?

**EDIT:** the code above resides in the framework, not in the app.

**EDIT2:** the code above is a utility function, and is not part of a struct or class.

Comment: If you in the custom framework, you can not get path for the main bundle, it is not in that way.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use `Bundle(for:Type)`:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let path = bundle.path(forResource: filename, ofType: type)
```

or search the bundle by `identifier` (the frameworks bundle ID):

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.myframework")
```

Comment: The code is not part of a class or struct, so there is no `self`. I have edited my question.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, using `Bundle(identifier: "com.myframework")` did the trick.

Answer (score 12):

Swift 5

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
let path = bundle.path(forResource: "filename", ofType: ".plist")
```

Answer (score 6):

Try below code to get the custom bundle:

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CustomBundle", ofType: "bundle")
let resourceBundle = Bundle.init(path: bundlePath!)
```

**Update**

If in your framework, try this:

```
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[YourClass class]] URLForResource:@"YourResourceName" withExtension:@".suffixName"];
```

Comment: The code to access the bundle is in the framework, not in the app.

Comment: What is `YourClass` ?

Comment: @Koen test `[self class]`

Comment: @Koen See this link at 38-line, I exchange with the author long time ago because of the issue: https://github.com/pikacode/EBForeNotification/blob/master/EBForeNotification/Classes/EBMuteDetector.m

Comment: I fail to understand what the `class` is; `loadPListFromBundle` is just a utility function (in `Swift`, BTW).

Answer (score 4):

Simply specify the class name of the resource and below function will give you the Bundle object with which the class is associated with, so if class is associated with a framework it will give bundle of the framework.

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: <YourClassName>.self)
```

Comment: Not applicable to my question, see the comments to the answer of @aircraft below.

Comment: YourClassName is the class of resource or xib name and is a better way of getting bundle rather than search by bundle identifier.

Comment: I am loading a plist with lots of data. Please explain how this relates to `YourClassName`

Comment: it is related to your question, in you case it's a plist but someone else might want to get the bundle from a resource and might come here to look for the answer.

Comment: Sure, but that's not how SO works. In that case it is better to ask a separate question.

Comment: Take it easy, you don't have to accept this as the answer, as I said it's related to your question and someone else might find it useful, i am only trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
import class Foundation.Bundle

private class BundleFinder {}

extension Foundation.Bundle {
    /// Returns the resource bundle associated with the current Swift module.
    static var module: Bundle = {
        let bundleName = "ID3TagEditor_ID3TagEditorTests"

        let candidates = [
            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into an App.
            Bundle.main.resourceURL,

            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into a framework.
            Bundle(for: BundleFinder.self).resourceURL,

            // For command-line tools.
            Bundle.main.bundleURL,
        ]

        for candidate in candidates {
            let bundlePath = candidate?.appendingPathComponent(bundleName + ".bundle")
            if let bundle = bundlePath.flatMap(Bundle.init(url:)) {
                return bundle
            }
        }
        fatalError("unable to find bundle named ID3TagEditor_ID3TagEditorTests")
    }()
}
```

From: [Source](https://www.fabrizioduroni.it/2020/10/19/swift-package-manager-resources/)

---Update---

It provides 3 kind of most comment usages about how to get the correct bundle, this is very useful especially when you are developing your own framework or using Cocoapods.

Comment: Please add some explanation why you think this is a useful answer.

Comment: @koen, apparently, It provides 3 kind of most comment usages about how to get the correct bundle, this is very useful especially when you are developing your own framework or using Cocoapods.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include your explanations.